# Capturing the frames online without slowing the pace of the game

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, rendering

How to capture the background frames while a unity game is running?

I already knew

cam.Render();

Texture2D image = new Texture2D(cam.targetTexture.width, cam.targetTexture.height); image.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, cam.targetTexture.width, cam.targetTexture.height), 0, 0);

and then

converting the texture into an image using EncodeToPng/JPG

But what I have seen using this extra cam.render and encoding to png and capturing the frames differently slow down the operation drastically, takes huge time to do this.

How can I directly get the textures or frames online while a game is running, maybe from the OpenGL calls which GPU are using?

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: how many frames you want to capture per second?

Comment: I want whenever a player (or camera) changes its position the frame should be captured. Following the normalcy, I am trying to have 60 FPS. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Unity's Video Capture API to record gameplay? There are tutorials and instructionals you can find, but the Unity Documentation is a good place to start.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsholographic-videocapture.html

It's flexibly implemented, so you can work around whatever requirements you want in terms of fps, resolution, etc based on your application and how it's set up.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @Antic. But I want to capture the frames only mainly in .png format, not the video? can you please tell me how to get the frames only from this? can you also tell me how much this video capturing slow down the pace of the on-going game?